# Trying to link SDL in MinGW's G++ is failing miserably.. :/

Tags: c++, linker, g++, mingw

Late last night I got bored.. so I began writing a small 'Noughts and Crosses' type game in C++ and SDL. I wrote a fair majority of the basic part of the game, but when I compiled it to check for errors I got the error message: Undefined reference to WinMain@16; So, "Aah, simply add -lmingw32 should help!", I was thinking.

g++ main.cpp -o nac.exe -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -SDL_image

Now it went and gave me this: Undefined reference to SDL_main;

I see no wrong with what I have done, I tried moving -lmingw32 to the right side, middle-left and middle-right just to be sure.. Nada!

I don't think it would be my source code, but just incase: http://pastebin.com/r7fEAkr4
ALso I think I kinda failed with the array definition... but I will fix that shortly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Erkling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main function needs this exact signature: `int main(int, char**)`

Comment: Thank you so very much for the fast reply. :) I see that all my previous games/apps had that prototype ( signature? ) now!

Again, thank you so much!

Comment: So that you understand what is going on: C defined that the first function called is `main`. It is defined that any prototype from `void main(void)` to `int main(int, char*)` is accepted. However, SDL uses a nasty trick: SDL has it's own `main` function, and uses: `#define main SDL_main`. In SDL's code, after some processing, it calls `SDL_main`, which enters your code. Since c++ allows function overriding, defining `SDL_main(void)` doesn't cause any problems except SDL is looking for `SDL_main(int, char**)`, thus the error.

Comment: Aah! I see, is this because SDL was programmed in plain C?

Comment: Not exactly. When your compiler sees a definition of `main`, it known it is has to use the C interface. However, when you write `main` with `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`, it transforms to `SDL_main`. This time it doesn't know that it has to use the standard C interface and treats it as a C++ function when compiled with g++, allowing overriding. It also overrides the definition that the main function can be `void main(void)`, since it doesn't know it's a main. Since for him it's not a C function, it is ignored by SDL. I think somewhere in the header, SDL_main(int, char*) is defined as a C function.

Comment: You'll also know that the SDL_main trick is mostly here because of Windows, which has a WinMain definition which is different from the ANSI main. On Linux, SDL's `main` just calls `SDL_main`, while on Windows there's a whole treatment of the arguments such that they are the same when passed to `SDL_main`. Yet another reason I don't like Windows.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. :)

Btw, totally agree with you about the whole Windows-hate thing. I usually use FreeBSD or Slackware, but when I write things like games I kinda need a GUI.. so I use Windows. ( I prefer not using GUI's in BSD/Linux distros for some reason :P )